# Maximum size allocated by calloc() in C

Tags: c

In the Samsung R&D placement test a question was there:
What's the maximum size allocated by calloc?
a)16k  b)32k  c)64k  d)128k

I dont know the right answer. Can anyone tell me the right answer for it.

Comment: Option e - None of these

Comment: How do I know this question was asked in India? Been there, done that, total BS!!!

Comment: I guess you forgot to provide the code from the test

Comment: Work it out do a google

Comment: It was asked in the Samsung Technical test.@vaibhav desai

Comment: With compliant C, `SIZE_MAX` is at _least_ 65535. so a) and b) are wrong.  I agree with others that the answer is e).  Suspect test was fishing for c).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Theoratically** the maximum is the value one could request. For

```
void *calloc(size_t nmemb, size_t size);
```

that is:

```
nmemb * size

SIZE_MAX * SIZE_MAX
```

With `SIZE_MAX` being the limit of `size_t`.

However as `size_t` is the result of the `sizeof` operator the **theoratical** maximum is limited to `SIZE_MAX`.

Answer (score 7):

This is a nonsense question, as it is highly system-dependent. None of the answers is right; there are system where you can `calloc()` mega- and gigabytes of memory.

Comment: Yeah that's what confused me. So I marked 32k. I don't why they give such qestions?

Answer (score 0):

It's related to your compiler and your machine architecture,For example:

```
int = 2 byte in some machine
int = 4 bye in some machine
```